# Why QSslSocket class is missing?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, smtpclient

i have building a small app in QT 4 for send email , but i have a problem is missing "QSslSocket" class.
i had configured :

```
configure -static -debug-and-release -no-exceptions
nmake
```

OS win 8.1 64bit ;Visual Studio 2010 ultimate ;QT 4.8.4

Comment: Did you build `Qt` from source?

Comment: yes , i build Qt from source

Comment: Ok. And are the other classes from the `Network` module available? `QNetworkAccessManager` for example. If not, try re-building again `Qt` with the `network` module enable.

Comment: Oh, and please post the code you're trying to compile and the error you got. It seems that `Qt 4.8` does have `QSslSocket`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsslsocket.html

Comment: tks , but other classes from the QtNework have available ( QNetworkAccessManager  , QTcpSocket , ... ) , only "QsslSocket" class is missing .

Comment: copy paste error information

Comment: i get code example from http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=20

Comment: here is error information :      error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QSslSocket'

Comment: Did you provide OpenSSL-Library upon compilation of Qt? Otherwise it cannot compile QSsL (has to be enabled with ``-openssl``)

Comment: OpenSSL support.............yes

Comment: i installed openssl from http://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1e.exe .  but "QSslSocket" is unavailable.